# Does Android have any default Activity to handle auth failure Intent?

Tags: java, android, account

I'm learning android account through official doc now. And, I'm confused on the part of dealing with auth failure. Link is below:

https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate#RequestAgain

From the doc and sample code, I understand that on auth failure, we'll get an Intent keyed on `AccountManager.KEY_INTENT` and we should use `startActivityForResult(intent)` to deal with the failure like shown below:

```
private class OnTokenAcquired implements AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> {
    @Override
    public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result) {
        ...
        Intent launch = (Intent) result.getResult().get(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
        if (launch != null) {
            startActivityForResult(launch, 0);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

But, the doc does not mention that we need to create a new Activity to handle this intent or Android do have any default for same. So, is that mean there is already some Activity defined to deal with this intent, provided by Android OS and what we want to do is only get the result in `onActivityResult()`?

Answer (score 0):

Android does not have this default activity,Usually handled by yourself.

Comment: It seems strange to me because if we need to create a new activity to handle this, the doc should mention what is the action of the intent, so that we can set the action to the corresponding activity's intent-filter?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create a new activity. You need to handle the onActivityResult event in the activity in which you are trying to authenticate with OAuth2.

Comment: But do we need to create a new activity to be launched by the intent?